# PHP twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

Sometimes my content has two columns otherwise 1 column.

- One option is have  base twig template and then ovveride the block of content and write `<div class="col-2">bla bla</div> <div class="sidebar">blah</div>`    **OR**  `<div class="col-1">blah bal</div>` if i need 1 column.   In this case the downside is that i have to write these stuff always.
- Another solution would be to have 3 basic templates 1) base , 2)  one-col, 3)two-col and then ovveride the blocks i want. one-col would have( inner_content) two-col would have (inner_content) and (sidebar_content) with no downside apart that 2 more files.
- Another solution would be to change only a twig variable that would change the class of the div col-2 or col-1.

What is the best solution here ? I think that having 3 templates is the best as it allows defaults etc when needed.. Any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the *base* / *one-col* / *two-col* approach, according to the [Three-level Inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance) method described in the documentation.